# How to get content from my router with AJAX

Tags: ajax, router

Let me explain in details what I want... I need to get content from my router via this address `http://user:password@192.168.1.1/dhcp_table.html` from this line (class name):

```
<td class="data_table_data" align="center">

**PC name**

</td>
```

I would like to see my result like this:

```
PC name
```

Is this what I am looking for? If yes, then how?

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass username and password to the router as ajax parameters. You should also specify `dataType: 'html'` as well:

```
var url = "http://192.168.1.1/dhcp_table.html",
    username = "<username here>",
    password = "<password here>";

var auth = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  dataType: 'html',
  username: username,
  password: password,
  headers : { Authorization : auth },
  success: function (data) {
    var dhcpTable = $(data);
    alert('Text of table = '+dhcpTable.filter('.data_table_data').text()); 
  }
});
```

**Edit**: added base64 authentication.

Comment: I tried this one, but doesn't work for me. My router use Basic Auth (Base64). Is this a problem?

Comment: Ah. Added base64 authentication and headers parameter in ajax.

Comment: Still doesn't work... or how I get all source from 192.168.1.1, not just class name?

Also i get error: OPTIONS http://192.168.1.1/dhcp_table.html [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 217 ms]

Comment: Hmm. Somethings to try: remove the *username* and *password* options from ajax call, but leave *headers* option. Or try the keyword `Authentication` instead of `Authorization`.